# Couldn't use svg image in react

Tags: reactjs

Folder structure looks like:

```
public--
        |-- myImage.svg
src--
     |-- MyModal.jsx
```

Code :

```
<Modal>
          <img src="../public/myImage.svg" alt="" />

          <p>
            done
          </p>

</Modal>
```

I tried giving the full path,but still doesn't show the img

Comment: The `src` should be just `/myImage.svg`.

Comment: As I see it it's not a svg problem but an URL problem. Check out the file system you are using and be aware if that public folder is inside the project structure. Maybe for some reason it can't just see the folder and then can't import it

Answer (score 0):

The file or the folder might look different at runtime depending on how your project gets compiled/bundled.

You can however get around this by importing the image as a module and using that as the `src`:

```
import myImage from "../public/myImage.svg";

<img src={myImage} />
```

Comment: I get `Module not found: You attempted to import ../public/myImage.svg which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.`

Comment: Are you using a framework of some kind to bootstrap your app? Looks like something is limiting you to the src directory only.